# sndfile.h not found on OS X

Tags: gcc, libsndfile

I'm trying to install libsndfile on OSX, and I used homebrew (brew install libsndfile). But when I try to compile some example code with `#include <sndfile.h>` using gcc it says sndfile.h cannot be found, but when I check in `/usr/local/include` it's right there. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on which compiler you're using you may need to add:

```
-I/usr/local/include
```

to you your command line, e.g.

```
gcc -Wall -I/usr/local/include foo.c -o foo
```

Comment: Can you clarify? Where do I add that?

Comment: It depends - are you using a makefile, an Xcode project, or just compiling from the command line ?